# Remove vertical lines in table in coreldraw

Tags: corel-draw, tables

I'm creating a sign up list in coreldraw, it's a table with 3 columns and 15 rows. How do I remove the vertical lines in the table while keeping only the horizontal lines?

Answer (score 2):

After you are done with the table and adding data into the table, select your table and press CTRL-K to break the table into lines, then select the table again and ungroup the lines of the table by pressing CTRL-U. Then select the all the vertical lines and either delete them or change their outline to no-color.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In CorelDRAW 2017 (confirmed this works in X5 as well), this can be accomplished but needs to be done one column at a time:

Highlight the cells in the column where you want to remove the horizontal border:
[image]

In the Borders drop-down, select Inside:
[image]

Set the border size to None:
[image]

Final product:
[image]

EDIT:  I just noticed that the OP asked about vertical lines, not horizontal (as I have shown).  Regardless, the process is still the same for a row versus a column.